# format date column in csv with bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, formatting

I have multiple comma separated files in a folder.
Each CSV file looks like following:

```
"Column1","Date","Column2"
"fdfsd","20151023","rwer"
"fsdsf","20151023","jjfg"
.
.
```

I need to modify the 2nd Date column to display the date in this format "10/14/2015" or "2015-10-14".

Please can someone help me with this?

Thanks

This is what i have tried:

```
cat test.csv | while read line ; do echo $line\;$(date -d "%Y%m%d" "+ YYYY/MM/DD") ; done
```

usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ...
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
"Column1","Date","Column2";

usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ...
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
"fdfsd","20151023","rwer";

usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ...
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
"fsdsf","20151023","jjfg";

Comment: Sorry about not posting earlier. Please have a look. Thanks

Comment: Can you use `perl` or `awk` or `python`?

Comment: I can try using awk..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this `awk` to reformat a given `date` string:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR>1{cmd = "date -d \"" $2 "\" \"+%Y-%m-%d\"";
       cmd | getline out; $2=out; close("uuidgen")} 1' file
"Column1","Date","Column2"
"fdfsd",2015-10-23,"rwer"
"fsdsf",2015-10-14,"jjfg"
```

Comment: Hi.. This works great.. Is there way i can use it to just modify the column in the file and not print the entire thing?

Comment: It will be: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR>1{cmd = "date -d \"" $2 "\" \"+%Y-%m-%d\""; cmd | getline out; $2=out; close("uuidgen")} 1' file > _file.tmp && mv _file.tmp file`

Answer (score 4):

Since you just need to insert hyphens into the date, this is a string manipulation problem not a date manipulation problem:

```
sed -i.bak -re 's/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/\1-\2-\3/' *.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Python has a very robust csv module.

You can do:

```
$ python -c '
import csv
import datetime
import fileinput

def line_out(line): 
    print ",".join(["\"{}\"".format(e) for e in line])

csv_data=csv.reader(fileinput.input())
line_out(next(csv_data))
for line in csv_data:
    line[1]=datetime.datetime.strptime(line[1], "%Y%m%d").date().isoformat()
    line_out(line)' file
```

Prints:

```
"Column1","Date","Column2"
"fdfsd","2015-10-23","rwer"
"fsdsf","2015-10-23","jjfg"
```